# Unable to populate selectlist from model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The details:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5
- No DB, no login, just plain front-end web billboard.
- No need for a 100% accurate list of countries, as long as things like Canada and USA aren’t missing it is Good Enough.

I seem to be tying myself up in knots here, trying to get a list of countries to be displayed in a drop-down select list.

My model:

```
[DisplayName("Country")]
public string Country { get; set; }
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _CountryList;
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList {
  get {
    List<string> CultureList = new List<string>();
    CultureInfo[] getCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
    foreach(CultureInfo getCulture in getCultureInfo) {
      RegionInfo GetRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(getCulture.LCID);
      if(!CultureList.Contains(GetRegionInfo.EnglishName)) {
        CultureList.Add(GetRegionInfo.EnglishName);
      }
    }
    return CultureList.OrderBy(x => x.ToString()).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() }).ToList();
  }
  set { _CountryList = value; }
}
```

My View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text"), " « ‹ Choose your country › » ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The error message that comes back is the ever-infuriating,

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Which is code for, “You f**ked up, and good luck figuring out what it is because I am not telling”.

I have gone so far as to try to manually fill the model with a manually-crafted select list, to zero effect. Where am I going wrong here?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I have now tried,

```
RegionInfo country = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("en-US", false).LCID);
List<SelectListItem> countryNames = new List<SelectListItem>();

//To get the Country Names from the CultureInfo installed in windows
foreach(CultureInfo cul in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)) {
  country = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo(cul.Name, false).LCID);
  countryNames.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = country.DisplayName, Value = country.DisplayName });
}

//Assigning all Country names to IEnumerable
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> nameAdded = countryNames.GroupBy(x => x.Text).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Text);
return nameAdded;
```

with zero success. Same results - “u dun goofed”.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Country:")]
public string Country { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, Model.CountryList, " « ‹ Choose your country › » ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller:

```
namespace Project.Controllers {
  public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
      return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Demo() {
      var model = new DemoViewModel() {
        model.CountryList = CountryList.getCountries()
      };
      return View(model);
    }
  }
//dummy content, just to try to "populate" ****ANYTHING****
  public class CountryList {
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getCountries() {
      IList<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem> {
      new SelectListItem{Text = "United States", Value = "B"},
      new SelectListItem{Text = "Canada", Value = "B"},
      new SelectListItem{Text = "United Kingdom", Value = "B"},
      new SelectListItem{Text = "Texas", Value = "B"},
      new SelectListItem{Text = "Washington", Value = "B"}
      };
      return items;
    }
  }
}
```

You see where I try to attach `CountryList.getCountries()` to the `model.CountryList`:

```
Cannot initialize 'DemoViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
```

***tears out hair***

Comment: Firstly, it just needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountryList, ...)` - its pointless to create a 2nd identical SelectList from the first one. Which line of code in your getter is throwing the error?

Comment: ---I am not seeing the difference between your code and mine. Please highlight.--- WHOOPS strike that. It's been a long day.

Comment: You do not need to create a 2nd dropdown list in the view using `new SelectList(Model.CountryList, ....)` - its already a SelectList :). And why do you have a private field for `_CountryList ` when you never `get` it (only `set` it)?

Comment: No change. Sorry. Removing the `new SelectList` has no effect.

Comment: It means that `Model.CountryList` is `null` so you need to debug your code. And code like that belongs in a method, not a property. And a lot of what your doing makes no sense. Your view model should contain `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }` and in your controller you set the value (preferably by calling a service that returns your list of countries.

Comment: You are going to have to break out the crayons and the construction paper. All my attempts to do so are either just as successful as previously, or produces invalid code in the first place. Please see Edit 2 for an example.

Comment: In Edit 2 - change `model.CountryList = CountryList.getCountries()` to `CountryList = CountryList.getCountries()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `CountryList.getCountries()` returns a collection of `SelectListItem`,

Do either

```
var model = new DemoViewModel(); 
model.CountryList = CountryList.getCountries();
return View(model);
```

Here you are creating an object of `DemoviewModel` class and setting the `CountryList` property explicitly.

or this

```
var model = new DemoViewModel {
                                   CountryList = CountryList.getCountries()
                              };
 return View(model);
```

This is called **Object initialization**. Here you are creating an object and initializing the `CountryList` property value along with that.

Assuming your DemoViewModel class another property to hold the selected item.

```
public class DemoViewModel
{
  public List<SelectListItem> CountryList { set;get;}
  public string Country { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your view which is strongly typed to this view model,you use DropDownListFor helper method.

```
@model DemoViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.Country,Model.CountryList)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: _Looks at second code block above_ -- _Looks at code from other internal projects_ -- Uhhhh.... _looks at what I had done above_ -- Let's just call it a very long day at the end of a very long week, k? I'm feeling rather stupid right about now.

Comment: you just have a small error in the code where you are assigning the collection. If you fix that, your code will work fine.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured that out. This last week has been a rather nightmare week, and 4-6hrs a sleep per night wasn’t helping me much in the mental agility department. Your second code block above is what kicked me in the arse into the right direction, thanks.